# Testing an API wrapper

Tags: node.js, api, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js

I'm writing an API wrapper for an external API, to be used in our application.

I have adopted a test-driven approach for this project but since I have little to no experience with writing API wrappers, I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

I understand that I should not be testing the external API, nor should I be hitting the network in my tests. I'm using Nock to mock my requests to the API.

However, I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly.

I made some requests to the API using curl and put the (XML) response in a file, for example: `/test/fixtures/authentication/error.js`:

```
module.exports = "<error>Authorization credentials failed.</error>"
```

Since I don't want to hit the network, but want to make sure my wrapper parses the XML to JSON, I figured I needed sample data.

My test looks like this:

```
describe("with an invalid application key", function() {
  var cl, api;
  before(function(done) {
    api = nock(baseApi)
          .get('/v1/auth/authenticate')
          .reply(200, fixtures.authentication.error);
    done();
  });
  after(function(done) {
    nock.cleanAll();
    done();
  });
  it("returns an error", function(done) {
    cl = new APIClient(auth.auth_user, auth.auth_pass, "abcd1234");
    cl.authenticate(function(err, res) {
      should.exist(err);
      err.should.match(/Authorization credentials failed./);
      should.not.exist(res);
      api.isDone().should.be.true;
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

With my tested code looking like this:

```
APIClient.prototype.authenticate = function(callback) {
  var self = this;
  request({
    uri: this.httpUri + '/auth/authenticate',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      auth_user: this.user,
      auth_pass: this.pass,
      auth_appkey: this.appkey
    }
  }, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
      return callback('Could not connect to the API endpoint.');
    }
    self.parser.parseXML(body, function(err, result) {
      if (err) { return callback(err); }
      if (result.error) { return callback(result.error); }
      self.token = result.auth.token[0];
      return callback(null, result);
    });
  });
};
```

Now, this seems to be working fine for the authentication side of things (I also have a 'success' fixture, which returns the 'success' XML and I check if the returned JSON is actually correct.

However, the API I'm using also has endpoints like:

`/data/topicdata/realtime/:reportxhours/:topics/:mediatypes/:pageIndex/:pageSize`

I'm not sure how to test all (should I?) possible combinations with URLs like those. I feel like I can hardly put 30 XML responses in my fixtures directory. Also, when mocking responses, I'm afraid to miss out on possible errors, edge cases, etc. the external API might return. Are these valid concerns?

If anyone has any pointers, and/or knows of any open-source and well-tested API wrappers I could take a look at, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I think your concern is very valid and I suggest you to also build tests using [Zombie](http://zombie.labnotes.org/) or other simular request-based testing frameworks.